# Removing Zeroes before and after data sample

Tags: sed, awk

I have several data samples that I need to grop the zeroes before and after the data sample. However there are zeroes between the data sample that I must keep for obvious reasons. How can I do this with awk or maybe sed?

Thanks.

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
4.40
21.20
17.44
18.24
2.08
19.92
14.56
21.20
6.64
0
27.04
32.24
65.28
12.00
40.80
30.48
30.16
30.24
0
62.56
6.56
29.76
0
43.84
13.44
17.12
54.48
23.52
30.72
29.04
11.04
14.56
5.76
31.60
13.68
11.20
17.44
17.44
0
36.56
16.64
32.40
18.40
0
104
9.84
1.68
63.84
19.28
5.76
28.00
12.64
0
0
136
13.28
23.28
1.20
19.12
27.28
0
2.88
36.16
27.44
13.60
36.32
20.96
15.84
23.12
10.24
.96
43.60
8.32
0
0
61.60
20.00
31.36
32.80
0
72.32
27.04
9.52
21.28
2.08
44.48
11.20
26.40
19.92
18.40
0
78.32
13.04
38.88
6.24
66.64
4.56
25.12
43.20
4.00
58.08
18.40
2.48
20.32
15.76
24.96
0
28.40
28.64
32.72
6.64
14.72
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: What do you mean with grouping? Do you want to delete all trailing and leading lines where the value equals 0? Perhaps you want to also include the example with the wanted modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will drop all zeros from the beginning and the end of the file while keeping zeros in the middle:

```
awk '/[^0]/{if (z)print substr(z,2);print;z="";f=1;next} f{z=z"\n"$0}' file
```

#### How it works

- `/[^0]/{if (z)print substr(z,2); print;z=""; f=1; next}`

  If the present line has any character on it other than zero, `/[^0]/`, then we do the following:

  1. If the variable `z` is non-empty, we print it, skipping its first character.
  2. We print the current line (the one with the non-zero).
  3. We set `z` back to an empty string.
  4. We set the flag `f` to 1 to signify that we have seen a line with a non-zero.
  5. We skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
- `f{z=z"\n"$0}`

  If we get to this command, that means that the line contains no non-zero character.  If we have seen a non-zero line, in other words if `f` is 1, then we append to `z` a newline and the current line.

#### Example 1

Consider this file:

```
$ cat file2
0
0
2.08
0
18.40
0
0
```

The command produces the following output:

```
$ awk '/[^0]/{if (z)print substr(z,2);print;z="";f=1;next} f{z=z"\n"$0}' file2
2.08
0
18.40
```

#### Example 2

Using your input file

```
$ awk '/[^0]/{if (z)print substr(z,2);print;z="";f=1;next} f{z=z"\n"$0}' file
4.40
21.20
17.44
18.24
2.08
19.92
14.56
21.20
6.64
0
27.04
32.24
65.28
12.00
40.80
30.48
30.16
30.24
0
62.56
6.56
29.76
0
43.84
13.44
17.12
54.48
23.52
30.72
29.04
11.04
14.56
5.76
31.60
13.68
11.20
17.44
17.44
0
36.56
16.64
32.40
18.40
0
104
9.84
1.68
63.84
19.28
5.76
28.00
12.64
0
0
136
13.28
23.28
1.20
19.12
27.28
0
2.88
36.16
27.44
13.60
36.32
20.96
15.84
23.12
10.24
.96
43.60
8.32
0
0
61.60
20.00
31.36
32.80
0
72.32
27.04
9.52
21.28
2.08
44.48
11.20
26.40
19.92
18.40
0
78.32
13.04
38.88
6.24
66.64
4.56
25.12
43.20
4.00
58.08
18.40
2.48
20.32
15.76
24.96
0
28.40
28.64
32.72
6.64
14.72
```